# Why can I not deserialize this custom struct using Json.Net?

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a struct representing a DateTime which also has zone info as below:

```
public struct DateTimeWithZone
{
    private readonly DateTime _utcDateTime;
    private readonly TimeZoneInfo _timeZone;    
    public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone, 
                        DateTimeKind kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)
    {
        dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, kind);        
        _utcDateTime = dateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc 
                      ? TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZone) 
                      : dateTime;
        _timeZone = timeZone;
    }    
    public DateTime UniversalTime { get { return _utcDateTime; } }
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get { return _timeZone; } }
    public DateTime LocalTime 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(_utcDateTime, _timeZone); 
        } 
    }
}
```

I can serialize the object using:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var dateTimeWithZone = new DateTimeWithZone(now, TimeZoneInfo.Local, DateTimeKind.Local);
var serializedDateTimeWithZone = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateTimeWithZone);
```

But when I deserialize it using the below, I get an invalid DateTime value (DateTime.MinValue)

```
var deserializedDateTimeWithZone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeWithZone>(serializedDateTimeWithZone);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have too much logic in your class for a serializer. They best work with simple 'plain data' types (i.e. bunch of properties with getters and setters)

Comment: @Maxwell, I am sure my struct has no way as much logic as the built-in DateTime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to write a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to properly serialize and deserialize these values.  Add this class to your project.

```
public class DateTimeWithZoneConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (DateTimeWithZone) || objectType == typeof (DateTimeWithZone?);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dtwz = (DateTimeWithZone) value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("UniversalTime");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dtwz.UniversalTime);
        writer.WritePropertyName("TimeZone");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dtwz.TimeZone.Id);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var ut = default(DateTime);
        var tz = default(TimeZoneInfo);
        var gotUniversalTime = false;
        var gotTimeZone = false;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                break;

            var propertyName = (string)reader.Value;
            if (!reader.Read())
                continue;

            if (propertyName == "UniversalTime")
            {
                ut = serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(reader);
                gotUniversalTime = true;
            }

            if (propertyName == "TimeZone")
            {
                var tzid = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzid);
                gotTimeZone = true;
            }
        }

        if (!(gotUniversalTime && gotTimeZone))
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("An DateTimeWithZone must contain UniversalTime and TimeZone properties.");
        }

        return new DateTimeWithZone(ut, tz);
    }
}
```

Then register it with the json settings you're using.  For example, the default settings can be changed like this:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeWithZoneConverter());
    return settings;
};
```

Then it will properly serialize to a usable format.  Example:

```json
{
  "UniversalTime": "2014-07-13T20:24:40.4664448Z",
  "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

And it will deserialize properly as well.

If you want to include the local time, You would just add that to the `WriteJson` method, but it should probably be ignored when deserializing.  Otherwise you'd have two different sources of truth.  Only one can be authoritative.

Also, you might instead try [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which includes a `ZonedDateTime` struct for this exact purpose.  There's already support for [serialization](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/serialization.html) via the [NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/) NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I am well aware of Jon's work on Noda Time however I still wanted to know how to fix this particular problem.

Comment: Not an answer, should be a comment.

Comment: @EZI - Expanded to include the `JsonConverter` that is required to do this properly.

Answer (score 17):

Just declare the constructor as follows, that's all

```
[JsonConstructor]
public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime universalTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone,
                    DateTimeKind kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)
{
    universalTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(universalTime, kind);
    _utcDateTime = universalTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc
                    ? TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(universalTime, timeZone)
                    : universalTime;
    _timeZone = timeZone;
}
```

Note: I only added `JsonConstructor` attribute  and changed the parameter name as `universalTime`

Comment: This is an oversimplification and it *doesn't* work.  Take a look at the JSON itself.  There is entirely too much serialized for the time zone.  (It should only serialize the time zone id, not every property in the class.)  Also, when deserialized, despite using the `JsonConstructor`, the date values still have the wrong values.  there's really no shortcut solution.  This is a custom value object, and thus a `JsonConverter` is required.

Comment: I was having an issue with my custom struct. All I needed was the [JsonConstructor] to solve my issue. Thanks for this.