# Newtonsoft.Json will not call the constructor when deserializing?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following class:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Color ErrorColor { get; set; }
    // other things
}
```

The `Color` struct is defined in a library I am using:

```
public struct Color
{
    public Color(uint rawValue) { /* ... */ }
    // other things
}
```

If I attempt to desterilize the following data:

```
{
    "ErrorColor": 16711680
}
```

With the following code:

```
var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(data);
```

This exception gets thrown:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value 16711680 to type 'Discord.Color'.

How can I get Newtonsoft to call the constructor of this type when deserializing? I know you can make custom `JsonConverter`'s, but I only need it for one property, not all of them.

Comment: In short, the deserializer can only deal with parameterless constructors. You will need a custom converter like the answer here
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726273/why-can-i-not-deserialize-this-custom-struct-using-json-net

Comment: Take a look at [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489).  In your case you want to serialize your `ErrorColor` as a `uint` rather than a `string` but the idea is similar.  Json.NET will generally only use a parameterized constructor when deserializing a JSON **object** or **array**.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConstructorAttribute and [JSON.net: how to deserialize without using the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017716/3744182).